# Possible to launch link in a different browser?

Tags: browser

We have a situation where the VF page will be launched in a Chrome browser. 
The VF page will have a link, when users click that link we want the resulting window to open in IE 11.

There is also a scenario where we want the reverse to happen for a different page.

Comment: Why would you even want to force a user to open a link in browser different than they are working?

Comment: This question does not seem specific to Salesforce and might be better [so].

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, there's nothing *you* can do about it (short of using a zero-day exploit to take over the OS or browser to execute code remotely). Browsers will typically open new windows of the same browser, and for unknown types, open the default application for that file type. There's no way that you can control this behavior in JavaScript.